# jquery plugin Fancybox not working

Tags: jquery, plugins, fancybox

Hej.

This is my first time working with Jquery, and I am trying to get the plugin FancyBox v2.1.7 to work on a gallery I made. When I click on the thumbnail of one of the pictures in the gallery, the picture pops up and is shown in a larger version (as it should). However it is impossible to swipe between the pictures and the little arrow icons are not their either.

I have tried to follow the steps shown in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IPIO-T0sfU and the plugin is downloaded from: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license.

I've downloaded the zip file and extracted the file from it. I put the lib and source file in the folder with my other documents and linked to them in my Portofolio html document. Then I put the javascript snippet in the end of my portfolio html document in script tags. I've been sitting with it for so long now, that I no longer can see the mistakes. This is a picture of how my files are ordered in my lib folder

[image]

And in my source folder

[image]

And in my root folder. Portfolio kopi 2.html is the one I am working on right now (where I am trying to get the fancybox gallery to work. I'm very new at this so I sometimes have two versions of a documents, so that I can always go back to before something went wrong.

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class ="portfolio-tekst"><h2>Portfolio</h2></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>


 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 filter hdpe"> 
            <div class ="thumbnail">
            <a href="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" a class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="imgs/pexels-photo.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
            </a>
          <p class="caption">Thumpnail images</p>
        </div>
     </div>
```

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/source/jquery.fancybox.js¢"></script>




   <script>


$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });

   </script> 








</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is your issue? If you want to have swiping, then use v3

Comment: I dont know how to be more specific sorry :/ But the issue is that it is not possible to swipe between the pictures like your supposed to with the fancybox plugin... the little arrow signs that indicates that you can swipe between pictures are not there.. Its basically just a normal image gallery where you can click on the thumbnail pictures and see them in a  larger version..